# Volume keys only react on every second hit

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm using a Tuxedo InfinityBook with elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki.

When I hit <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>VOL. UP/DOWN</kbd>, the changes only take effect on every second hit. So, to lower or raise the volume by one step, I have to hit <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>VOL. UP/DOWN</kbd>] twice.

I noticed that the system seems to "save the state" of the volume bar even though no changes take place: When I hit <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>VOL. DOWN</kbd> and <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>VOL. UP</kbd> in a row, nothing happens, but when I do the same again after that, the volume first decreases and then increases by one step, as one would expect. I hope, this is understandable.

Strange thing is, this bug is also present when I boot another OS from a Live USB...

Also, the "underlying buttons", which are "?" and "`´" in my case, work normally.

I tried to set other key combinations to raise/lower volume via dconf-editor (e.g. "<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>"), then it works fine! I want to use my native media keys for this though, so this is not an acceptable workaround.

Typing `gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up` in the terminal, as suggested by many, also doesn't solve it.

This problem only occurs with the volume buttons, e.g. the brightness keys, mute key,... work as expected.

I've run out of ideas by now – maybe anyone has experienced similar issues and managed to solve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this could be reproduced by the manufacturer, but they won't put any effort into it because my notebook from 2015 is apparently too old... Seems to be related to something on hardware side, so I don't see a realistic chance to get this fixed and therefore closing this thread.